# Registry permissions in Windows 10

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-10, registry, dac

An application running as a non-admin in Windows 7 has read/write permissions to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, but apparently not in Windows 10.

A lot of applications store stuff in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` which are usually meant to be for all users, and they work fine (like the Visual studio) without being run as an admin, but not my application.

How can I make my own application access `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` without having to run it as an admin user?

The issue is that `RegCreateKeyEx()` and `RegOpenKeyEx()` return `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` in Windows 10, when I run the application  as a standard user, but they work fine if I run it as an admin user.  I don't want to run the application as an admin just for this.

**Update**

Based on the comments, a non-admin application only has read access to HKLM and I confirmed that with calling application with only READ writes and they can read but it is noted that windows 7 also doesn't have write access but my test application does work fine in Windows 7. Here is the code

```
void CRegistryPermissionsView::OnBnClickedButtonRegkey()
{
    CRegKey regKey;
    LRESULT ret = 0;

    CString strKey = _T("Software\\ATestApp\\TestAppNode");

    ret = regKey.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKey, KEY_ALL_ACCESS);

    if (ret == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        ret = regKey.Create(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKey);

    if (ret == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        ret = regKey.SetStringValue(_T("Entry"), _T("EntryValue"));

        if (ret == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            AfxMessageBox(_T("Success"));
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why the above works in Windows 7 but my main question is where should we store global settings that apply to all users in Windows 10?

Yes, I can create the registry entries through installer which has admin rights but my application would still want to update some of the settings! Do we have to store this locally on a drive now?

All the configuration in the application needs to be applicable to all users.

Comment: Non-admin user does not have the rights to write to HKLM since Vista was released. You can *read* from HKLM, but not write to it, without admin privileges. RegOpenKeyEx will fail on Windows 7 for HKLM if asking for write access as well. If it's working for you, you've got admin rights.

Comment: The way to do this is to create whatever keys you need in your installer (which needs to run elevated) and change the protection on them so that they can be accessed by a regular app.  I do this - I will post some code tomorrow.

Comment: @KenWhite it does work for Windows 7 and I am certainly not running it as administrator, never had any issues with windows 7.  I will check on permissions for windows 10 tomorrow and will try only read permission there.

Comment: Win7 does *not* allow you to write to HKLM without admin privileges. The documentation for RegCreateKeyEx tells you so, as does any effort to write to HKLM without admin rights. I dealt with this issue extensively when Vista was released, because it broke existing code and I had to fix it. If you're being allowed to write to HKLM in Windown 7, either you've got admin privileges or you (or someone else) modified privileges from the defaults to allow it.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks, I will check on it tomorrow. That's quite interesting that it works. I wrote a small test application just to test registery and it was working fine too. Not sure if somehow current user is added to registery permission.

Comment: @zar That's most unlikely.  I agree with Ken, having had to code round this issue on Vista and later.  I will post some code for you that implements my suggestion above.

Comment: @KenWhite I updated the question based on comments and posted code. The dilemma with Windows 7 remains.

Comment: The general Windows philosophy is that anything that can affect other users requires administrator privileges. Makes sense really. I'm quite surprised that Windows 7 allowed you to modify HKLM at all, because as @KenWhite says it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: The dilemma is why you need to write to HKLM in the first place, let alone without elevation. Changes made to HKLM not only affect every user, but also affect the entire OS, so an invalid (or malicious) change can render the OS inoperable. There's a reason Vista and above require elevation for writing to it, and there's seldom a good reason to bypass that restriction.

Comment: @KenWhite The reason is that we want application configurations to be persistent across all users. I think originally this was what HKLM was for to store settings that should be used by all users. One can argue that it's theoretically right but practically, many times, persistent settings are desirable. So basically its like windows is pushing out persistent settings even if it makes sense in some cases?

Comment: @KenWhite Ahh..that might solve the issue!

Comment: @KenWhite I tested that but it doesn't have access to HKEY_USERS\.Default either in Windows 10 either but Windows 7 has.

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 now, so I can't test Win 10 until I'm at a different machine later today. In the meantime, [this MSDN article might help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724836(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I think I found out why it was working in Win 7 and not on Win 10. I suspect (but haven't been able to confirm yet) that they turned off [Registry Virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884(v=vs.85).aspx) in Win 10.

Comment: @MarkRansom It's logical that a user Joe can't write to a profile of Mark but there should be a space that all users can use for user-independent settings.

Comment: @KenWhite I can't find any reference to it anywhere but it almost has to be that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comments above, what you have to do here is to create whatever keys you need in HKLM in your installer (which needs to run elevated) and then change the protection on them so that they can be accessed by an app running with standard permissions (i.e., as a member of group `BUILTIN\Users`, and running non-elevated).

Here's the code to 'unprotect' a registry key.  Code written in Notepad so may not quite compile and it's obviously a bit hacky, sorry.

Utility function BuildAce (was missing originally, sorry about that):

```
// Build an access allowed, access denied, system alarm or system audit ACE.  Caller must free.
ACE_HEADER * BuildACE (PSID sid, int ace_type, int ace_flags, ACCESS_MASK ace_mask)
{
    int sid_len = GetLengthSid (sid);
    int ace_len = sizeof (ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE) - sizeof (DWORD) + sid_len;
    ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE *ace = (ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE *) malloc (ace_len);
    memset (ace, 0, ace_len);
    ace->Header.AceType = ace_type;
    ace->Header.AceFlags = ace_flags;
    ace->Header.AceSize = ace_len;
    ace->Mask = ace_mask;
    memcpy (&ace->SidStart, sid, sid_len);
    return (ACE_HEADER *) ace;
}
```

Utility function AddOrRemoveACE:

```
// Add or remove an ACE to/from an ACL
// Returns a copy of the original ACL with the relevant changes made; caller must free
// Sequence of ACE's must be:
//      not inherited, denied
//      not inherited, allowed
//      inherited, denied
//      inherited, allowed
ACL *AddOrRemoveACE (ACL *acl, ACE_HEADER *new_ace, bool add)
{
    int acl_size = acl->AclSize;
    if (add)
        acl_size += new_ace->AceSize;

    ACL *new_acl = (ACL *) malloc (acl_size);
    BOOL ok = InitializeAcl (new_acl, acl_size, ACL_REVISION);
    assert (ok);

    // Add new denied ACE at start of list
    if (add && new_ace->AceType == ACCESS_DENIED_ACE_TYPE)
    {
        ok = AddAce (new_acl, ACL_REVISION, MAXDWORD, new_ace, new_ace->AceSize);
        assert (ok);
    }

    // Copy all non-inherited ACE's, removing anything matching new_ace
    for (int i = 0; ; ++i)
    {
        ACE_HEADER *old_ace;
        if (!GetAce (acl, i, (VOID **) &old_ace))
            break;
        if ((old_ace->AceFlags & INHERITED_ACE) == 0 &&
            (old_ace->AceSize != new_ace->AceSize ||
             memcmp (old_ace, new_ace, old_ace->AceSize) != 0))
        {
            ok = AddAce (new_acl, ACL_REVISION, MAXDWORD, old_ace, old_ace->AceSize);
            assert (ok);
        }
    }

    // Add new allowed ACE at end of list
    if (add && new_ace->AceType == ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE)
    {
        ok = AddAce (new_acl, ACL_REVISION, MAXDWORD, new_ace, new_ace->AceSize);
        assert (ok);
    }

    // Copy all inherited ACE's
    for (int j = 0; ; ++j)
    {
        ACE_HEADER *old_ace;
        if (!GetAce (acl, j, (VOID **) &old_ace))
            break;
        if (old_ace->AceFlags & INHERITED_ACE)
        {
            ok = AddAce (new_acl, ACL_REVISION, MAXDWORD, old_ace, old_ace->AceSize);
            assert (ok);
        }
    }

    // Store the actual size of the acl data (not reversible)
    ACL_SIZE_INFORMATION asi;
    ok = GetAclInformation (new_acl, &asi, sizeof (asi), AclSizeInformation);
    assert (ok);
    new_acl->AclSize = (WORD) asi.AclBytesInUse;
    return new_acl;
}
```

Utility function AddOrRemoveRegKeyACE (returns error code):

```
// Add or remove a registry key ACE.  hKey must have WRITE_DAC access
DWORD AddOrRemoveRegKeyACE
    (HKEY hKey, bool add, int ace_type, PSID sid, ACCESS_MASK access_mask)
{
    LONG    err;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR psd;
    DWORD buflen = 1024;

    // Read current security information    
    for ( ; ; )
    {
        psd = malloc (buflen);
        err = RegGetKeySecurity (hKey, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, psd, &buflen);
        if (err == 0)
            break;
        free (psd);
        if (err == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
            continue;
        return err;
    }

    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_RELATIVE *sdr = (SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_RELATIVE *) psd;
    ACL *pdacl = (ACL *) ((BYTE *) sdr + sdr->Dacl);

    ACE_HEADER *ace = BuildACE (sid, ace_type, CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE, access_mask);
    ACL *new_acl = AddOrRemoveACE (pdacl, ace, add);
    free (ace);
    free (psd);

    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
    BOOL ok = InitializeSecurityDescriptor (&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
    assert (ok);

    ok = SetSecurityDescriptorControl (&sd,
        SE_DACL_AUTO_INHERIT_REQ | SE_DACL_AUTO_INHERITED,
        SE_DACL_AUTO_INHERIT_REQ | SE_DACL_AUTO_INHERITED);
    assert (ok);

    ok = SetSecurityDescriptorDacl (&sd, TRUE, new_acl, FALSE);
    assert (ok);

    // apply the security descriptor to the registry key
    err = RegSetKeySecurity (hKey, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, &sd);
    free (new_acl);

    return err;
}
```

And now a function to grant acces to a registry key to everyone in group 'Users'.  Returns TRUE on success:

```
BOOL grant_access_to_registry_key (HKEY hKey)
{
    // Give the Users group access to hKey
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY sia = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
    PSID pUsersSid;
    BOOL ok = AllocateAndInitializeSid (&sia, 2,
        SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID, DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_USERS,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &pUsersSid);
    if (!ok)
        return FALSE;
    ok = AddOrRemoveRegKeyACE (hKey, true, ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE,
            pUsersSid, KEY_ALL_ACCESS) == 0;
    FreeSid (pUsersSid);
    return ok;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how do we execute this code in the installer? This look like c++ so this could be a separate executable and the installer calls it?

Comment: No idea, I don't know (and don't want to know!) what installer you are using.  But yes, that sounds viable, just so long as you can launch the process elevated.  The above code should build fine in Visual Studio if you include the right header files.  MSDN will help you track those down.

Comment: The code nearly builds but I get only 2 errors. BuildACE() and ReportLastError() functions are undefined. Could you please add those functions too? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I hacked it out of my installer and just pasted it in.  I will update it tomorrow.

Comment: Good morning @zar.  I have now updated my code, it should be OK now.

Comment: One thing you want to say is the function `grant_access_to_registry_key` return 0 if failed and non-zero (1) if success. It looks like your description is the other way round. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, just keeping you on your toes :) I edited the post, thanks.